# POST request generating a GET request (303 See Other)

Tags: jquery, post

Using jquery I make a post request and my console is indicating that the POST then becomes a GET. However it no longer passes the posted form to the GET request and then, I can no longer do what I intend.

Why would the server decide to change my post to a get request?

More importantly - how do I preserve the post data, which is currently being lost by the redirect.

Comment: Server decided that (303). Unless we have the server code, we cannot know 'why' it did so.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection

303 See Other (since HTTP/1.1)
    The response to the request can be found under another URI using a GET method. When received in response to a POST (or PUT/DELETE), it should be assumed that the server has received the data and the redirect should be issued with a separate GET message.

Comment: Thank you but I still don't understand why.